# Using a for loop in Java to process a string

Tags: java

I can never get this to loop all the way through the string. I can't use >= or == in this loop it stops it from working :( help

```
    int s = 0;
    String twocharacters = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){

        char c = value.charAt(i);
        char w = value.charAt(i + 1);

        if (c == '/' && w == '*' && s == 0){
            s = 1;
        }
        else if (c == '*' && w == '/' && s == 1){
            s = 0;
        }
        else if (s == 0 && c != ' ' && c != '*' && c != '/'){
            twocharacters += c;
            System.out.println(twocharacters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what the "value" is

Comment: You'll also want to stop one character before the end because of the `charAt(i + 1)`.

Comment: `char w = value.charAt(i + 1)` will lead to an exception when `i == value.length() - 1`

Comment: if you want to do a charAt(i + 1), you should run the loop only till i < length -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the last iteration (`i = value.length() - 1`), assigning `value.charAt(i + 1);` to `w` would throw an exception because you are at the end of the string and cannot get the next character.

Try:

`for (int i = 0; i < value.length() - 1; i++){`